# How can I disable ext4's automatic defragmentation?

Tags: ext4, defragmentation

I'm running tests that require some files to be heavily fragmented. I came up with a method to generate fragmented files, but something is working in the background to defragment them. I'm using `hdparm --fibmap` and I see it start out with thousands of fragments, then a lot of disk IO later, I see it have under a hundred fragments.

Is it possible to disable this?

Answer (score 2):

Ext4 doesn't "defragment" file's in the background. At most it will delay block allocation and then merge writes to the file.